# How to turn this Vim command into a function?

Tags: shell, vim

In Vim, I run the following to sort selected lines by length:

```
%!perl -e 'print sort { length($a) <=> length($b) } <>'
```

How do I go about turning this into a function so that I don't have to type this all out?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Look into `:help 40.2`

Comment: Were it me, I'd create a Perl script `sortbylength` which I'd place in my `$HOME/bin` directory (along with 500+ other scripts and programs), and then I'd run that when necessary.  But I'm probably hopelessly old-fashioned about such things.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd like my vim setup to be self contained where possible. If I relied on dependencies, I'd have to copy the entire setup when I move to different machines. Coupling is important to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be simpler to define a command in your .vimrc that takes this action. For example:

`command SortByLength %!perl -e 'print sort { length($a) <=> length($b) } <>'`

Then you can execute `:SortByLength` as you please, or map a keystroke to execute this command. See `:help 40.2` for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Final command was: `command -range SortByLength :<line1>,<line2>%!perl -e 'print sort { length($a) <=>        length($b) } <>'` to sort by a range.

Comment: @Roxy if you're going to use `:<line1>,<line2>` then you should remove the `%` following it. Cheers